# Deleted VirtualBox VDI while VM is running?

Tags: boot, command-line, virtualbox, virtualization, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted an ubuntu.vdi while the VM is running. Oddly, the VM is still responsive and running without issues. I expect shutting down the VM will result in total data lose. Any help would be amazing right now. **Is there anything I can do to recover the .vdi or preserve the VM operating system**?

Host OS and VM are using Ubuntu 18.04 with Virtualbox 6.1.

Comment: Are you sure it is deleted? is it gone from its location and are you sure you have the right location?\
What did you use to delete it? if you used a GUI, check the trash folder.

I would have thought you would have got a lock/busy error?

Comment: I was looking for large files on the host OS with various `find` commands, eg: `find /home/ -type f -size +500M -exec ls -lha {} \;`, but at some point I changed `ls` to `rm`. The .vdi is no longer in `/home/user/VirtualBox/Ubuntu-VM/`, but other vbox files are still present

Comment: I have a solution using dd, but it is a long set of directions and is going to take some explaining and typing. You would essentially be cloning your current live drive from inside your VM directly into another VM with a live install disk... it will be tricky, so I am hoping @73Gavin solution works for you. So tell us if it does

Comment: @WU-TANG, I appreciate that. I'm currently copying `cp /proc/13518/fd/38 ~/recovered.vdi` as described in the linux.com article. It's taking some time as the VM is over 40Gb. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: Thanks again. Booting the recovered VDI seems to work without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once you close the file, recovery will be harder.  Give this a read, I think you will find success:

https://www.linux.com/news/bring-back-deleted-files-lsof/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.